# continually multiply many columns to form a new variable

Tags: r, function, loops

I recently want to continually multiply many columns and form a new variable in R.

I found that there is a `prod` function in R, which could provide the product of all elements in many vectors or matrices.

However, I do not want to get the product of all element. Instead, I want to get the product of each row.

I can do it with code with loop as following:

```
t <-
 data.frame(x1=round(round(runif(10),1)+1),
            x2=round(round(runif(10),1)+1))
for(i in 1:nrow(t)) {    t$y[i] <- prod(t[i,]) }
```

However, I wonder whether there is more efficient way or easy function, in that I can used like `prod(t$1:t$2)` and get the result I want.

Comment: you can try `library(matrixStats); rowProds(as.matrix(t))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `base` variant of @akrun's answer would be

```
x <- matrix(1:20, ncol = 4)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    6   11   16
[2,]    2    7   12   17
[3,]    3    8   13   18
[4,]    4    9   14   19
[5,]    5   10   15   20

apply(x, 1, prod)
[1]  1056  2856  5616  9576 15000
```

In contrast to `matrixStats::rowProd()`, this also works on a `data.frame`.

```
x <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:20, ncol = 4))
x$new <- apply(x, 1, prod)

> x
  V1 V2 V3 V4   new
1  1  6 11 16  1056
2  2  7 12 17  2856
3  3  8 13 18  5616
4  4  9 14 19  9576
5  5 10 15 20 15000
```

Answer (score 4):

A convenient function would be `rowProds` from `matrixStats`, but that would require a `matrix`

```
library(matrixStats)
rowProds(as.matrix(t1))
#[1] 2 1 4 4 2 4 1 2 4 1
```

---

If we need a `base R` option, which works on `data.frame`, then use

```
Reduce(`*`, t1)
#[1] 2 1 4 4 2 4 1 2 4 1
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
t1 <- data.frame(x1=round(round(runif(10),1)+1),x2=round(round(runif(10),1)+1))
```